# Can the print() command in R be quieted?

Tags: r, printing

In R some functions can print information and return values, can the print be silenced?

For example:

```
print.and.return <- function() {
  print("foo")
  return("bar")
}
```

returns

```
> print.and.return()
[1] "foo"
[1] "bar"
>
```

I can store the return like:

```
> z <- print.and.return()
[1] "foo"
> z
[1] "bar"
>
```

Can I suppress the print of `"foo"`?

Comment: Question like this suggest you are doing something in a very dirty way...

Comment: The problem is that it's not my function thats printing and returning, short of diving into the imported library, I want to quiet the output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use hidden functional nature of R, for instance by defining function

```
deprintize<-function(f){
 return(function(...) {capture.output(w<-f(...));return(w);});
}
```

that will convert 'printing' functions to 'silent' ones:

```
noisyf<-function(x){
 print("BOO!");
 sin(x);
}

noisyf(7)
deprintize(noisyf)(7)
deprintize(noisyf)->silentf;silentf(7)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
?capture.output
```

Comment: Nice, so in my example: dev.nil <- capture.output(z <- print.and.return()) does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I know that I might be resurrecting this post but someone else might find it as I did. I was interested in the same behaviour in one of my functions and I just came across "invisibility":

It has the same use of `return()` but it just don't print the value returned:

```
invisible(variable)
```

Thus, for the example given by @ayman:

```
print.and.return2 <- function() {
  message("foo")
  invisible("bar")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need the side effect of printing in your own functions, why not make it an option?

```
print.and.return <- function(..., verbose=TRUE) {
  if (verbose) 
    print("foo")
  return("bar")
}


> print.and.return()
[1] "foo"
[1] "bar"
> print.and.return(verbose=FALSE)
[1] "bar"
>
```

Comment: Nice use of a default; the issue is that it's not my function.

Comment: In many cases where you'd do this, you should probably use `message` rather than print. (That is, in the cases where your `"foo"` is a string, rather than an R object for which you want to use the print method.)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with hadley and mbq's suggestion of `capture.output` as the most general solution.  For the special case of functions that you write (i.e., ones where you control the content), use `message` rather than `print`.  That way you can suppress the output with `suppressMessages`.

```
print.and.return2 <- function() {
  message("foo")
  return("bar")
}

# Compare:
print.and.return2()
suppressMessages(print.and.return2())
```