# apriori call in arules package writes output even when storing to a variable; how to prevent?

Tags: r, arules

I have this basic example where I am trying to store the output of the `apriori` call to a variable. However, I still get the console output. I need to run this on thousands of scenarios and don't want this output showing up.

Is there a way to avoid it?

```
library(arules)
df <- data.frame(basket = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), item = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'))
as <- as(split(df[, 'item'], df[, 'basket']), 'transactions')
ar <- apriori(as, list(target = 'frequent itemsets'))
```

Comment: the warning or text? `apriori(..., control = list(verbose = FALSE))` or [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681719/can-the-print-command-in-r-be-quieted) but ignore hadley's terrible answer

Comment: Ah...downside of ignoring documentation on parameters you 'think' you don't need. Thanks!